# Remote Drush Commands Not Found

Tags: drush

I'm using a new host for my website and I requested drush access to my site. They said it's all set and told me to run drush commands as such $ ../drush/drush command

I test it out with $ ../drush/drush status and everything works as it should.

The problem comes when I try to run drush commands remotely via my alias file. Everytime time I drush @remote I get drush: not found

I even set path-aliases to point specifically at %drush and %drush-script.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you use, '%path-aliases', either specify the full path to Drush, or ensure that the Drush that you are calling (e.g. `drush`) is on your PATH.

**Example:**

```
$aliases["mysite"] = array (
  'uri' => 'mysite.org',
  'root' => '/path/to/drupalroot',
  'remote-host' => 'myisp.com',
  'remote-user' => 'www-admin',
  'path-aliases' => 
  array (
    '%drush-script' => '/home/myuser/drush/drush',
  ),
);
```

If setting the PATH in your .bashrc, always do so at the very top of the file.  It is common for boilerplate (host-provided) .bashrc files to have a line somewhere in the middle that exits prematurely when not in interactive mode -- and Drush makes remote Drush calls non-interactively in most instances.